# GCP: how to get a bearer token for aiplatform with c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, token

I don't understand how I can get a bearer token: I'm trying this:

```
var url = "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-bison:predict";
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));

var oidcToken = await credentials.GetOidcTokenAsync(OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(url));
var token     = await oidcToken.GetAccessTokenAsync();
var client    = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Content = new StringContent(promptJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response        = await client.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

based on https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/api-quickstart and using the Google.Apis.Auth nuget package.

I get the error message:

> "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

But I have to admit: I'm not sure how to use the OidcTokenOptions and I couldn't find useful documentation.
So I'm kind of certain that this part is incorrect.

The json key file (GoogleCredential.FromFile) is from a service account from the same gcp project.
if I use a token using "gcloud auth print-access-token" it works fine (but of course this is not how it should be done).

Can anyone please help me finding out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest using the Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1 NuGet library instead, so you don't need to do any of this yourself. See https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest for docs (In this case I suspect you want PredictionServiceClient, but I haven't checked for sure.)